# Get records for past 24 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp

I have an SQL query that displays timestamp. How do I get records for past 24 hours. We are using MS SQL Server 2012, but the following query

```
select DATEADD(SECOND, TIME_STAMP /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') 
as Date_and_Time from [dbo].[V_AGENT_SYSTEM_LOG] 
where EVENT_SOURCE = 'sylink'and EVENT_DESC like '%Downloaded%'
and TIME_STAMP >= SYSDATE() - 1
```

returns error

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'SYSDATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

Thank you

Comment: you need getdate() instead of sysdate and datediff to subtract 1 day

Comment: Say the date and time right now is 7/25 at 5pm. Do you want all records going back to 7/24 at 5pm, or all records going back to 7/25 at midnight?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia I would like all the records going back to 7/24 5pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sysdate is Oracle - use Getdate()

```
select DATEADD(SECOND, TIME_STAMP /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') 
as Date_and_Time from [dbo].[V_AGENT_SYSTEM_LOG] 
where EVENT_SOURCE = 'sylink'and EVENT_DESC like '%Downloaded%'
and TIME_STAMP >= GETDATE() - 1
```

Comment: I get the error "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime."

Comment: You should use DATEADD even for days instead of relying on the default math process for datetime columns. DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())

Comment: That error is most likely in your epoch int column. If at all possible I would consider changing that to a datetime column.

Comment: @SeanLange how would I change epoch int column into datetime column? Because TIME_STAMP is the only column I have access to? I'm also trying to research this ...

Comment: According to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b4b8cba3-f4c8-40d7-960a-ce13467f09a8/convert-bigint-timestamp-to-a-datetime, I have already converted it with DATEADD(SECOND, TIME_STAMP /1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101') ... or is there something else I am not understanding

Comment: Well that did not change the datatype. It is a conversion of the existing integer to a datetime. My suggestion is to use datetime if possible. Obviously on some systems this isn't feasible. The reason you are getting an error is because you have some value(s) that when run through this conversion are outside the limits of the datetime datatype.

Comment: I'll create another question on how to convert system date to bigint, because there is no datetime column in the database schema I am using